# How do I configure a Bitnami Lightsail LAMP server to host a second web site?

Tags: apache, virtualhost, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have an AWS Lightsail Bitnami LAMP instance hosting a single web site.  I want to create a site for a second domain on the same server but haven't yet found success.

I copied and modified a httpd-vhosts.conf file and placed it in /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf.  I added an include statement to the end of /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf pointing to the new httpd-vhosts.conf file. When attempting to access either the new or old site the browser response is "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server".

There are two code blocks in /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf. This is one of them.  The second block is identical with "site1" changed to "site2".

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@site1.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/site1.com/htdocs"
        <Directory />
                Options -Indexes
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /opt/bitnami/apache2/site1.com/htdocs>
                Options -Indexes
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
    ServerName site1.com
    ServerAlias www.site1.com
    ErrorLog "logs/site1.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/site1.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

It appears that the new httpd-vhosts.conf file is being read because the new error and access logs are created.  The error log states "client denied by server configuration:".  The directory associated with this error in the error log is ...site1.com/htdocs as defined in the httpd-vhosts.conf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here.

Let's try these changes to fix the errors you are running into:

- Remove the following block

```
        <Directory />
                Options -Indexes
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
```

You only need the one that sets the configuration for the folder where you have your app's files.

- You will need to substitute these lines because they are not supported in the new Apache's version

```
Order allow,deny
allow from all
```

is deprecated. You need to use `Require all granted` when using Apache 2.4

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require

- Set the permissions of your app's folder properly

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apache2/site1.com/htdocs
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/bitnami/apache2/site1.com/htdocs
```

Comment: Thanks Jota!  Once your recommended changes were added both sites became accessible.